# BIDS\SSIS Derived day of week from date

Tags: date, bids, ssis-2008

I need to derive a column to be imported from CSV to ms sql. I have a date field, but I also need a day of week field, represented numerically. for example monday would be 2. Is there a way to do that as an expression in "Derived Column Transformation Editor", similar to the Weekday() function in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'BIDS' you mean 'SSIS', I believe you are looking for [the `DATEPART()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586.aspx): you can extract the day number using `DATEPART("DW",[MyDateField])`.  This will return 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday ... 7 for Sunday.

[Link with additional info](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d59c6a7b-6739-4e51-a516-215107fce145/how-to-find-the-day-of-week-in-ssis-2008)

Comment: Great!  Glad it helped, and +1 for the edited tags.  You can actually include versions by typing SSIS-xxx and looking for the correct year, FYI. The tag system here uses dashes as a space separator to identify a single tag value.